# What does it mean if VaR is equal to CVaR (Expected Shortfall)?

Tags: quantiles, finance

I've been running some VaR and CVaR tests for some stocks at 95% and 99% confidence limits. for some reason, when applying a 99% limit I seem to receive the exact same values for CVaR and VaR when using the modified expected shortfall method.

Will this have something to do with my data set having a skewness of -1.18, meaning it has a very large left tail? I'm a little stumped on this one.

Comment: How many data points are you looking at? Also, when you say modified expected shortfall, what precisely do you mean.

Comment: Im looking at 1250 observations, it's the daily closing prices for both GBP/EUR and Bitcoin across a few years. By Modified expected shortfall I mean that the Cornish-Fisher expansion is being applied. So within my Rcode, I'm able to use three methods of VaR - historical, parametric and modified ES. I've researched that the modified ES method is most suitable for datasets with large kurtosis, so I am using these results

Comment: One option might be that the bottom 1% of data all have the same value, so that the 1-st percentile or the mean of the bottom 1% of data would be the same.

Comment: @MaximilianJamesDonovan I can't say for sure why you would see those results. I would try simulating a skew t distribution (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/skewt/skewt.pdf) that matches the moments from your actual distribution and see if you get the same result.